# Why my JavaScript functions are not read by Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following js archive in the meteor client folder:

```
var o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7, o8, o9, o10;

window.onload = function() {

    o1 = document.getElementById("oculta1");
    o2 = document.getElementById("oculta2");
    o3 = document.getElementById("oculta3");
    o4 = document.getElementById("oculta4");
    o5 = document.getElementById("oculta5");
    o6 = document.getElementById("oculta6");
    o7 = document.getElementById("oculta7");
    o8 = document.getElementById("oculta8");
    o9 = document.getElementById("oculta9");
    o10 = document.getElementById("oculta10");

    o1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o2.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o4.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o5.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o6.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o7.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o8.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o9.style.visibility = "hidden";
    o10.style.visibility = "hidden";

};


function desplegar1() {
    o1.style.visibility = "visible";
    o5.style.visibility = "visible";
    o9.style.visibility = "visible";
    alert("hola");

}

function desplegar2() {
    o2.style.visibility = "visible";
    o6.style.visibility = "visible";
    o10.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

The problem is that **only the first function** is executed, the rest of all them(desplegar1,desplegar2...) don't work. Someone can help me?

Comment: What "don't work" means, exactly?

Comment: In the HTML file i have assigned those functions to some columns of a table, to be lauched when condition "onMouseOver" is fulfilled, but I do not get the result. Code: <tr>
  <td id="columna1" onmouseover="desplegar1()" onmouseleave="ocultar()"> <center>Inicio</center> </td> <td id="columna2" onmouseover="desplegar2()" onmouseleave="ocultar()"> <center>Servicios</center> </td> <td id="columna3" onmouseover="desplegar3()" onmouseleave="ocultar()"> <center>Acerca de</center></td> <td id="columna4" onmouseover="desplegar4()" onmouseleave="ocultar()"> <center>Carrito</center> </td> 
 </tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Inline code in the HTML is rather Angular style. If you want to code that way, you should look at `angular-compilers` Meteor package.

If you use Blaze, there is a high chance each of your JS file is scoped, so the HTML cannot directly access the functions declared with `var` in a JS file through its name. The function name may even be modified during build / minification.

The usual way with Blaze is to [*attach events to your template*](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events#attachingeventstotemplates) (`Template.<templateName>.events(eventsMap)`)

For example in your case:

```js
Template.myTemplateName.events({
  'mouseover td': desplegar1
});

function desplegar1() {
  o1.style.visibility = "visible";
  o5.style.visibility = "visible";
  o9.style.visibility = "visible";
  alert("hola");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! last doubt... concretely it could be ' mouseover [column id] ': desplegar1 ?

Comment: See http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps: the property is usually `eventtype selector`